# Swift generic constraints based on operator

Tags: swift, generics, operator-overloading

Suppose I want to add up all the values of an entry of an array. Not only integers, but also double values or some type I created myself which implements the + operator. So my question is: Is it possible to create such a function with a constraint that is based on the fact if the type implements the operator? Such as  or something like that (obviously THIS isn't working).

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you mind giving an example of an array like this? If they all implement the + operator maybe you can map the values to say double and then sum that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can approach the problem.

### IntegerArithmeticType

While I know of no explicit way to say "Hey Swift, I want to only allow type T where T has this operator", all types we commonly think of as capable of being added, subtracted, multiplied, and divided automatically conform to `IntegerArithmeticType`, which can be used as a generic constraint for any generic function or type.

For example:

```
func addAll<T: IntegerArithmeticType>(array: [T]) -> T {
    var count = array[0]
    for (index, value) in array.enumerate() {
        if index != 0 {
            count += value
        }
    }
    return count
}
```

Notice in this quick mock-up version I initialized `count` with the first value of the array and then avoiding double-counting by checking the index against 0 inside the for loop. I can't initialize `count` with 0 because 0 is an `Int` while I want `count` to be of type `T`.

You mentioned having your own types work with this too. One option is to have your custom type conform to `IntegerArithmeticType`, although it requires a lot more than just the `+` operator. For details on `IntegerArithmeticType`, see [SwiftDoc](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/IntegerArithmeticType/).

### Custom Protocol

If conforming to `IntegerArithmeticType` imposes some sort of limitation on you, you can create a custom protocol with the `+` function and whatever other requirements you would like. After all, operators are really just functions. Note that you can add conformance to already existing types with extensions. For example:

```
protocol Addable {
    func +(left: Self, right: Self) -> Self
    // Other requirements...
}

extension Int: Addable {}
extension Double: Addable {}
```